# Value lost between functions?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a simple text based battle game, and I have come across a(nother) problem. I have a main function and a battle function and in the battle function once you finish the battle, you gain a certain amount of XP, which is then (or should be) remembered by changing the value of player1.xp. Right after the battle sequence I set it so in the code if player1.xp >= 1 it will change the value of player1.level to "2". Though, whenever I run the code, for some reason the xp value gets lost when the battle function is finished. I know this because it prints out the value of player1.xp after the battle function, and it says "0". Here is the code:

```
import random
xp1 = random.randint(1,2)
class player:
    def __init__ (self, name, health, strength, defense, potion, xp, level):
        self.health = health
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense
        self.name = name
        self.potion = potion
        self.xp = xp
        self.level = level

    def changeHealth(self, h):
        self.health = h

    def addLevel(self):
        self.level += 1

    def subHealth(self, num):
        self.health -= num
        return self.health

    def subPotion(self):
        self.potion -= 1
        return self.health

    def addPotion(self, num1):
        self.potion += num1

    def addHealth(self):
        self.health +=2

    def addXP(self):
        self.xp += xp1

def battle1(enemy, player1, name1):
    player1 = player(name1, player1.health, player1.strength, player1.defense, player1.potion, player1.xp, player1.level)
    enemy = player("Rat", enemy.health, enemy.strength, enemy.defense, player1.potion, enemy.xp, enemy.level)
    print("Fight!")
    s = 0
    while s == 0:
        attack =input("Type 1 to attack, type 2 to use a potion.")

        if attack == "1":

            enemy.subHealth(15)

        elif attack == "2":

            if player1.potion > 0:
                print("You used a potion.")

            elif player1.potion <= 0:
                print("You don't have any potions! You are forced to attack.")
                enemy.subHealth(15)
        else:
            print("Your life depends on this!")

        if enemy.health <= 0:
            print("Congratulations, you won! You recieved", xp1, "xp!")
            player1.addXP()
            s = 2

def main():

    name1 = input("What would you like your name to be?")
    print("Hello,", name1, "you are on a quest to save otis from the evil Dongus. You must slay him, or Otis will poop.")
    player1 = player(name1, 10, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    enemy = player("Rat", 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    pick = input("You were walking along the path and found a potion! Press 'p' to pick it up.")
    if pick == "p":
        print("You added a potion to your inventory.")
        player1.addPotion = 1
    else:
        print("You have no potions, you should probably pick this one up.")
        print("You added a potion to your inventory.")
        player1.addPotion = 1
    battle1(enemy, player1, name1)
    print(player1.xp)
    if player1.xp >= 1:
        print("You leveled up. You are now level 2.")
        player1.addLevel()
    else:
        print("You have 0 xp.")

main()
```

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: The simplest explaination is that what you think is happening isn't.  I'd start by adding a print statement to `player.addXP` to confirm that it is called.

Comment: I tried that, and that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main` you create two `player` ([should be `Player`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) instances, and pass them to `battle1`:

```
player1 = player(name1, 10, 2, 1, 0, 1)
enemy = player("Rat", 15, 0, 0, 0, 0)
battle1(enemy, player1, name1)
```

In `battle1` you create two new `player` instances, based on the two argument instances, modify *the new instances*, and don't `return` anything:

```
# take three parameters (one of which is unnecessary)
def battle1(enemy, player1, name1):
    # replace two of the arguments with copies
    player1 = player(name1, player1.health, player1.strength, player1.defense, player1.xp, player1.level)
    enemy = player("Rat", enemy.health, enemy.strength, enemy.defense, enemy.xp, enemy.level)
    # original arguments now inaccessible
```

It is not clear why you expected that this would work, but the minimal fix is to *stop creating new instances in `battle1`*. Also, it might be clearer if you moved `xp1 = random.randint(1,2)` *inside* `battle1`.

Comment: Ok, I get why now. I took a class a week ago on Python and they told me to rewrite the instances in battle1. I didn't really understand why, but I just took their word for it. I guess the teachers weren't that great, as they taught me wrong styling too. I got rid of the instances and it worked. Thanks!